# Getting the URL of a web service that calls a class library

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, class-library

I have a web service that calls a class library.

In this class library i'm trying to find out the URL of the web service that calls the class library.

Is there a simple way of doing this??

Comment: don't you think this design startegy is a little intrusive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end

```
Dim tReq As New System.Web.Services.WebService
Dim tWSURI As String = tReq.Context.Request.Url.OriginalString
```

this requires you to add a reference to system.web

Answer (score 1):

You should not investigating from the class library what is the URL calling because this bind that library to works only with a web service, and this is not a good design startegy. Why do you need the URL ? Is in order to log the caller ? You can probably move the part of code interested in the URL *outside* the library.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SoapContext.Current.Actor.AbsoluteUri
```

This requires WSE 2.0 SP3.

Comment: does this work when i call the line from inside the class library and not from the webservice that calls it. Is there any way to do it without WSE 2.0 SP3